# Is it possible to exclude from compilation iOS 13 features if compiling using Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using the new iOS 13 background features, but for various reasons need to be able to build the codebase using both Xcode 10 and Xcode 11.

I've implemented the code like this:

```
#if canImport(BackgroundTasks)
import BackgroundTasks
#endif

...

 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      let backgroundCallProcessingRequest = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: kBackgroundTaskIdIdentifier_Authentication)
      ...
```

But with Xcode 10 get compilation issue of unresolved identifiers for BGAppRefreshTaskRequest etc.

Is there a way I can get this to be excluded from compilation with Xcode 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with Swift version to trick the compiler:

```
#if swift(>=5.1)
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        ,,,
    }
#endif
```

Since Xcode 10 contains Swift 5.0, This way Xcode can not check what it is inside (If you not install Swift 5.1 on it explicitly). But make sure to check it under Swift 5.1 (in Xcode 11 for sure).